# Cannot get rid of error: Unexpected implicit cast to `TextInputLayout`: layout tag was `EditText`

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

New to stack overflow and new to programming in general. I am creating an app on android studio and using Java. I am currently trying to create a login and register screen using firebase. I tried it on my own till I decided to follow a tutorial instead of as I have little experience. The tutorial instructor seems to have no issues but I can't get rid of this error: Unexpected implicit cast to `TextInputLayout`: layout tag was `EditText` on line 35.

I am not entirely sure why I get this error and I tried triple-checking my grammer and punctuation in the XML and Java files. I'm sure I am missing something simple and I cant see it. Here is my java code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextInputLayout inputEmail, inputPassword, inputConfirmPassword;
Button btnRegister;
TextView alreadyHaveAccount;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
ProgressDialog mLoadingBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
    inputConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputConfirmPassword);
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    alreadyHaveAccount = findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mLoadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        attemptRegistration();
    }
});


 alreadyHaveAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
}


private void attemptRegistration(){
String email = inputEmail.getEditText().getText().toString();
String password = inputPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
String confirmPassword = inputConfirmPassword.getEditText().getText().toString();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !email.contains("@gmail")) {
    showError(inputEmail, "Email  is not valid");

    } else if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() <= 7) {
    showError(inputPassword, "Password must be at least 8 characters");

    } else if (!confirmPassword.equals(password)) {
    showError(inputConfirmPassword, "Passwords do not match");
    } else {
        mLoadingBar.setTitle("Registration");
        mLoadingBar.setMessage("Please wait");
        mLoadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mLoadingBar.show();
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    mLoadingBar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else {
                    mLoadingBar.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Failed registration, please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}

private void showError(TextInputLayout field, String text) {
    field.setError(text);
    field.requestFocus();
}
```

}

and here is my XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:iconTint="@color/colorGray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputConfirmPassword" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="User Name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName|textEmailAddress"
    android:text="Email"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/username"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputConfirmPassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputPassword"
    tools:ignore="LabelFor" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alreadyHaveAccount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Already have an account?"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnRegister" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/registerText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputEmail"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And here are the stack trace errors I am getting:

> 2021-08-16 08:12:20.026 1168-2163/com.google.android.gms E/angh: Phenotype API error. Event # caox@a4027c2b, EventCode: 12 [CONTEXT service_id=51 ]
> anfl: 29503
> 2021-08-16 08:13:49.830 7617-7617/com.example.branchmanager W/e.branchmanage: Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->overlayPathToIdmapPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
> at auct.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):5)
> at auct.a(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):23)
> at anfv.b(:com.google.android.gms@201817022@20.18.17 (040700-311416286):3)
> 2021-08-16 08:13:50.972 7617-7617/com.example.branchmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.branchmanager, PID: 7617
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.branchmanager/com.example.branchmanager.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
> at com.example.branchmanager.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:33)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

Comment: Include your error and stack trace and indicate which line in your code the stack trace is referring to.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @alex I have added the stack trace.

Comment: What line of code produces that error?

Comment: @AlexMamo in my RegisterActivity.java, I get the error on this line: inputConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputConfirmPassword);  This is also the only error I get in the "Problems" menu. But I get a bunch of red error lines in the logcat's stack trace errors. I am not sure what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.branchmanager/com.example.branchmanager.RegisterActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

At this line of code:

```
inputConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputConfirmPassword);
```

Because you are trying to cast an object of type `EditText` to `TextInputLayout`, which is not possible.

In your layout file, the View with the following id:

```
 android:id="@+id/inputConfirmPassword"
```

Is an EditText and not a TextInputLayout. So to solve this, you should define in your activity class the `inputEmail`, `inputPassword` and `inputConfirmPassword` to be of type EditText and not TextInputLayout.

```
private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword, inputConfirmPassword;
```

And initialize them using:

```
inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
inputConfirmPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputConfirmPassword);
```

Comment: Thank you! I had tried that before but then got  6 more errors so I reverted back. But I tried it again and knocked out three of the errors by removing ".getEditText()" and the other three by right clicking and adding the needed imports and now the register activity is working and running on the virtual device! Once again, thank you.

Comment: That I will do!